# Alternatives to Microsoft Commerce Server

Tags: .net, e-commerce, microsoft-commerce-server

I'm trying to find an alternative to Microsoft Commerce Server as Microsoft has sold the product to a third party.

I need something suited for deploying a large scale e-commerce solution. The main requirement is that the software has to run on the .NET platform. Scalability, extensibility and ease of development are also appreciated.

In particular we would use the software to manage:

- products
- orders
- baskets
- customers
- discounts
- ...

Can anyone please give me some tips? I've been looking around on the web but there seems to be a shortage of .NET-based e-commerce software.

Comment: You might consider http://virtocommerce.com It's the most modern .NET eCommerce platform building both - for Azure and Standalone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx). Maybe this is what you're looking for.